# MySQL error "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value" in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1292

I have problem with my procedure. I try to take values from sales table and make a query using them.
Procedure looks like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS turnover;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE turnover()
BEGIN
    DECLARE col INT;
    DECLARE q TEXT;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE m TEXT;
    SET col = (SELECT count(DISTINCT article) FROM sales);
    SET q = "SELECT article, ";
    WHILE i < co DO
        SET m = (SELECT DISTINCT month FROM sales LIMIT 1 OFFSET i);
        SET q = q + "SUM(IF(month=" + m + ",value,NULL)) AS " + m;
        IF i < (col - 1) THEN
            SET q = q + ", ";
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET q = q + " FROM sales GROUP BY article";
    EXECUTE q;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL turnover();
```

I receive error:

Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',value,NULL)) AS '

How i can make it works?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this is your problem, but should this line `WHILE i < co DO` be `WHILE i < col DO`? The error usually happens when you try to compare a string to an int somewhere in your query.

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell with this. Why don't you log the generated statement? BTW, this probably doesn't even a need a stored procedure.

Comment: How is this question related to my MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @e4c5 that is a fair comment. For educational purposes I plopped in the below answer regardless of it perhaps being an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `col` issue was fixed or assumed in the below.

```
CREATE SCHEMA safe_Tuesday_01; -- safe sandbox
USE safe_Tuesday_01;    -- DO the work in this db to test it

-- a fake table, we need something
create table sales 
(   article varchar (100) not null,
    month int not null
);
```

**Step 1**, find out what the string looks like:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS turnover;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE turnover()
BEGIN
    DECLARE col INT;
    DECLARE q TEXT;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE m TEXT;
    SET col = (SELECT count(DISTINCT article) FROM sales);
    SET q = "SELECT article, ";
    WHILE i < col DO
        SET m = (SELECT DISTINCT month FROM sales LIMIT 1 OFFSET i);
        SET q = CONCAT(q,"SUM(IF(month=" + m + ",value,NULL)) AS ", m);
        IF i < (col - 1) THEN
            SET q = q + ", ";
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET q = CONCAT(q," FROM sales GROUP BY article");
    select q;
    -- EXECUTE q; -- No no no this is wrong anyway
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL turnover();
```

> SELECT article,  FROM sales GROUP BY article

Well that above `SELECT` does not look so hot. Repeatedly fix your logic in Step 1 to fix that string.

**Step 2**, when you fix the code above, plop in the below. Note, at the moment, it is not fixed. So do that, again, above.

But in the below, use a proper [`PREPARED STATEMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html) which you are not.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS turnover;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE turnover()
BEGIN
    DECLARE col INT;
    DECLARE q TEXT;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE m TEXT;
    SET col = (SELECT count(DISTINCT article) FROM sales);
    SET q = "SELECT article, ";
    WHILE i < col DO
        SET m = (SELECT DISTINCT month FROM sales LIMIT 1 OFFSET i);
        SET q = CONCAT(q,"SUM(IF(month=" + m + ",value,NULL)) AS ", m);
        IF i < (col - 1) THEN
            SET q = q + ", ";
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET q = CONCAT(q," FROM sales GROUP BY article");
    -- select q;
    SET @theSQL=q;
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @theSQL;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When done,

```
DROP SCHEMA safe_Tuesday_01; -- clean up, poof, sandbox is gone
```

[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is your friend. You missed this step. It is important that the [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html) works against a User Variable (with an `@` sign) and not a Local Var (from a `DECLARE`) else it will blow up. So I fixed that above with the `@theSQL`

Again, see the MySQL Manual Page [PREPARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html). It is important to get your string right. That is the point of Step 1. Only then do you move on to Step 2 and using it.

Comment: a well thought out answer

Answer (score 0):

It happens when `SELECT DISTINCT month FROM sales` doesn't return anything. On the next line, the query fragment is generated as `SUM(IF(month=,value,NULL)) AS` and, of course, there is an error there (maybe MySQL doesn't produce the correct error message, but this is where the error is).

And the cause of the error is the `WHILE` line that compares `i` against the unknown variable `co`. It should probably read:

```
WHILE i < col DO
```

But it doesn't fix the problem because `col` is the number of distinct values of `article` and you iterate from 1 to `col` over the distinct values of `month`. Most probably they are in different amounts and if the number of articles is bigger then the error will happen again.